# Disabled button when I refresh web page with F5

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have this JSF button:

```
<h:commandButton style="position:absolute; bottom:12px; right:12%;" styleClass="lbimage" onclick="this.disabled=true" value=" Edit Account " rendered="#{not AccountProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" action="#{bean.editAccount(true)}" >
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>&nbsp;
```

I added this JS in order to prevent double click when the code is executed:

```
onclick="this.disabled=true"
```

But when I refresh the web page with F5 the button is disabled when the page is loaded. How I can prevent this?

Comment: Check [this link](http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf-java/jsf2-how-to-create-a-global-ajax-status-indicator/) in order to use plain JSF 2 and JavaScript to solve your problem. Otherwise, it would be better to use a third party library that handles ajax status like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/ajaxStatusScript.jsf) or [RichFaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=status&skin=blueSky) (in the last case, you have to change the ajax status to work with a `<rich:popupPanel>`).

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="this.disabled=true"` and also use `oncomplete="this.disabled=false"`

Comment: Yes but you can use oncomplete function by using jquery. Or use primefaces or richfaces commandButton because these libraries support oncomplete

Comment: This won't work if user refreshes the page before the ajax request has been completed. This is a work for an ajax status.

Comment: Why we are conflicting this problem? There is simple solution I wrote before.

Comment: When the button event is executed, there can be a pop up which shows the process. So userr can wait  one or two second..

Comment: @mucayufa that's the purpose of ajax status, but your answer doesn't reflect it.